# preg_replace converting number string into exponent format

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Replicated problem : https://3v4l.org/n4qDK

So i have this code

```
    $pattern = array("/cash-equivalents_quarterly/" , "/total-assets_quarterly/");

    $replace_data["cash-equivalents_quarterly"] = 169677928570;
    $replace_data["total-assets_quarterly"] = 222617965672000000000;

    $formula["1"] = " cash-equivalents_quarterly / total-assets_quarterly";


    $amount1 = preg_replace($pattern,$replace_data,$formula["1"]);

    return array( "replace_data" => $replace_data , "formula1" => $formula["1"] , "pattern" => $pattern  , "amount1" => $amount1 );
```

I am getting amount1 as `169677928570 / 2.22617965672E+20` . While I expect as `169677928570 / 222617965672000000000`

This only happen when i do a ajax request and it goes process alot of data ( foreach loops ) backend.  But if I try to run this simple function alone it doesn't happen.

How can I fix this ?  I want plain number not the exponent format.

Addition Javascript part . Its angular

```
setFactory.submitFilterFormula($scope,function(results){
    console.log(results);
});

factory.submitFilterFormula = function($scope,callback){
        $scope.url = '/api/screener/submitFilterFormula';
        // console.log($scope.post_data);
        factory.doPostHttpRequest($scope).success(callback); 
    }
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Can't replicate. https://3v4l.org/AGt49

Comment: @PaulCrovella  the image text was just to proof that I am seeing that result in console log.   @ Jon  Yeah as I said it doesn't happen when running that 1 function alone. and thats one of the reason why pasted the picture. May be i will somehow try to replicate. :S

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any problem in the output of your PHP script. Where exactly is this number being converted to scientific notation?

Comment: Share javascript part.

Comment: @JonStirling here i replicated https://3v4l.org/n4qDK

Comment: @cjmling I believe that's because you changed it from a string to and int that is larger than the max int so it was converted to a double. Keeping the quotes still works fine. https://3v4l.org/FjKlo

Comment: @JonStirling yeah that seem to be the issue. My raw data is in integer, using `strval()` already converting into exponent. Any suggestion what should I do?

Comment: @cjmling You can pass it through `number_format` to get back to a non-exponent version e.g. `echo number_format($sillyLongDouble, 0, '', '');` but you'd potentially have to stop using preg_replace which casts the double to string for you, which causes the exponent notation. A `foreach` look and `str_replace` may work just as well and lets you use this.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks alot man . It worked. I just number_format it to string before putting into preg_replace. So it doesn't get converted. U may post as answer. I'll accept. Thanks

Comment: @cjmling As axiac points out, the number format "solution" isn't reliable, because floating-point. I suggest you remove the accepted from the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question used strings for replacement and, of course, it didn't have any issue. The updated question also doesn't show any issue.

It is a [documented behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php): the largest integer number that can be represented as integer in PHP on 32 bit systems and on all Windows system prior to PHP 7 is slightly greater than 2,000,000,000 (`2147483647` to be more precise). On 64 bit systems (except for PHP 5 for Windows), the greatest value that can be represented as integer is `2^63-1` (`9223372036854775807`).

Anything larger that these values is converted to `float` (`double`, in fact).

Your replacement value for `total-assets_quarterly` is about 23 times larger than this limit. If you don't need to do arithmetic operations with it then use it as string in PHP to avoid conversions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)